# What rules determine the apostrophe placement in "ham 'n eggs" and similar expressions?

Tags: punctuation, conjunctions, apostrophe

In expressions such as "ham 'n eggs", the conjunction *'n* appears to replace *and*, yet there is only one apostrophe to indicate the missing *a* and none for the missing *d* (i.e., no "ham 'n' eggs").

Is there a punctuation rule that governs this or is it just an idiosyncratic case?

Comment: The primary purpose of the apostrophe is to indicate that **something is missing from the 'word'** (in *"won't"*, for example, *"uld"* and *"o"* from *"would not"*). So it's effectively "standard practice" to only have a single apostrophe in *"ham 'n eggs"*.

Comment: @Fumble: I was under the impression that *won't* is a contraction of *will not*. *Wouldn't* is the contraction for *would not*.

Comment: @Robusto: Ooops! Wrong example! I was going to use "ain't", but deconstructing it got too awkward. I thought the general principle was we only use one apostrophe though, however much is discarded, but maybe that's wrong too - people mostly write **'tisn't**, I think.

Comment: @Fumble: It happens. :)

Comment: @Robusto: Well, Daniel seems to have shown that this particular one is atypical anyway - plus I've just remembered that in the UK it's always [Toys 'R' Us](http://www.toysrus.co.uk/index.jsf) when they're not using the reversed letter "R".

Comment: There’s also *“shake ’n bake”* or *“snarf ’n barf”*. Definitely missing apostrophes for the missing d’s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From a cursory glance, it appears to be a rule up to free variation. Consider:

1. From a naive search with the Google N-Gram viewer, it appears that `n'` has a slight edge.
   [image: Google N-Gram Viewer]

But if you zoom in to look at variations of `and eggs`, as well as `ham and eggs`, the picture gets murkier. Keep in mind that, since this is very informal usage, that it probably wasn't used frequently in the print media that the Google Ngram viewer searches through.
[image]
[image]

2. Examples from popular culture:

   - [Linens 'n Things](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linens_%27n_Things)
   - [Guns N' Roses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guns_N%27_Roses)
   - [Steak 'n Shake](http://steaknshake.com/)
   - ["Hot n Cold"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_N_Cold)
3. Variations of `Ham and Eggs`, culled from search engines:

   - [Ham N' Egg](http://hamneggrestaurant.com/) restaurant
   - [Ham N' Eggs](http://countryhamneggs.com/) restaurant
   - [Jackie's Ham 'n Eggs](http://directory.dmagazine.com/restaurants/Jackie-Ham-n-Eggs/21378) restaurant
   - ["Ham 'n' Eggs"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People%27s_Instinctive_Travels_and_the_Paths_of_Rhythm) rap song
   - [Ham 'n Eggs and Ham 'n Eggers](http://www.sandiegohistory.org/journal/92fall/battle.htm) referenced by the *San Diego Herald*, referring to the California pension initiative in 1938-1939

Conclusion: People tend to do one of 4 things to denote an unemphasized `and`:

1. `'n'`
2. `'n`
3. `n'`
4. `n` or `N`

As there is no broad consensus, and because people don't think about edge cases like these, I believe you could justifiably use any of them.

Comment: I notice that GN'R is the standout, but then, rock bands are not known for their close attention to orthography: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_umlaut

Comment: Hmm, I don't recall ever seeing n' as an abbreviation for "and". I just did a Yahoo search and the only example I could turn up was the band. I wonder if Google Ngram may be giving misleading results, like counting "n"'s that occur at the end of a quote or something. (Not sure what the rules are for Google Ngram.)

Comment: @Jay: I agree, the Ngrams can be tricky. I'll add some more data.

Comment: Guns N' Roses -> Guns Neuroses (or perhaps more accurately, Axl's Neuroses).

Answer (score 4):

If there'd've been a rule against multiple apostrophe I'd've known about it. Or somebody'd've.

*[More here](http://motivatedgrammar.wordpress.com/2007/09/11/preposterous-apostrophes-v-contractions/).*

Answer (score 2):

Could it be a question of phonetics? In *wouldn't*, we know that we have to insert a "schwa" or "mid central vowel", IPA ə, i.e. the most non-descript vowel possible, and very common in English, somewhere.

In *wouldn't* this sound doesn't actually come where the apostrophe is, but instead between the d and the n. The reason for putting it where it is references the fact of omitting the O sound and/or the letter O.

*Ham 'n eggs* is good because, if the apostrophe corresponds to the schwa, it is also where the schwa actually goes. But you could potentially achieve the same effect with *Ham n' eggs*.

If you try to go *Ham 'n' eggs*, however, two problems are created: lexicographically, it starts to look like "n" is quoted rather than being preceded and followed by phonetic markers. Phonetically you might be tempted to think that it's pronounced "ham ənə eggs", which would be seriously funny and potentially rather Italian.

Answer (score 0):

Ham 'n eggs does not appear to be the more common usage, so I think it unlikely that there is a grammatical reason for it.

[image: ngram]

Answer (score 0):

Since, in a contraction, the apostrophe denotes removed letters, and the word `and` has been contracted to `n` by removing both the `a` and the `d`, the correct written form would be:

> 'n'