# "Be-all and end-all"?

Tags: pronunciation

There is the saying "Be-all and end-all", meaning a fundamental property of something.

I noticed it is hard to pronounce because "and" and "end" sound the same.

Is one "and/end" omitted in pronunciation, i.e., "Be-all and end-all" => "Be-all end-all"?

Comment: _"and" and "end" sound the same_ - they don't sound the same in my part of the world.

Comment: If you say Be-all n end-all, you'll be good to go.

Comment: In fact, you'll sometimes see 'n' written for and in some common expressions to reflect pronunciation, as in this recipe for [Oven Fish ‘n’ Chips](https://www.tasteofhome.com/recipes/oven-fish-n-chips/). I'm wondering whether it should have two apostrophes, and not  look like open and close quotes, although this editor won't let me type it that way.

Comment: @DjinTonic Forecastle may be spelled forecastle, fo'c's'le or fo'c'sle (Wikipedia etc). Blue Magister at [What rules determine the apostrophe placement in ham n  eggs  and similar  expressions?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55855/what-rules-determine-the-apostrophe-placement-in-ham-n-eggs-and-similar-expre) posted a magisterial answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I wasn't referring to using one or two apostrophes, but rather using a curved open quote mark for the first because of software limitations. // BTW *maitre d'* is a rare case where a dictionary entry *ends* with an apostrophe.

Comment: @DjinTonic Yes; I was broadening to 'one or two apostrophes ( ... in addition to a mandatory orthographic style in either case)'?

Comment: Want pronunciation, consult a dictionary, and if the first doesn't have it, try another. [Collins provides pronunciation info](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/be-all-and-end-all) which suggests /ənd/ for the middle word; there are also recordings.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on an individual difficulty that is unlikely to have a general application.